# How to use tapered edges in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Tapered edges, which came out in September 2011, look pretty cool.

- http://www.graphviz.org/News.php/
- http://www.graphviz.org/pub/tmp/images/tapered-edge.png

I added style="tapered" to my edge options, which otherwise work fine:

```
  edge [color="black", minlen="1.3", arrowsize="0.6", style="tapered"]
```

But now I get this error:

```
$ dot -Tsvg demo.dot -o dot.svg
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style tapered - ignoring
```

It appears there is a warning for every edge in my graph.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?  I'm running ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly do not have the version of graphviz needed for tapered edges.

Try `dot -v`, if your graphviz version starts with 2.28 or less, tapered edges probably won't work. I get the same errors with a 2.28 version. Graphviz 2.29 however accepts the tapered style attribute.

Btw, once you a have an updated graphviz version working, you can use `penwidth` to change the thickness of the tapered edges.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  The version in the ubuntu repos is:  `dot - graphviz version 2.26.3`  That's too bad.  I tried downloading from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_ubuntu.php and it looks like there are just a ton of dependencies that get broken if I try to jump to 2.29.